# Execute a python function if a button in a Javascript function has been pressed

Tags: javascript, python, html, streamlit, tsx

I'm building an acoustics related website with Python and Streamlit.
I need to record audio while a file is playing: for this task I found [this library](https://github.com/stefanrmmr/streamlit_audio_recorder) that manages the access to the user microphone via the browser's Media-API and records, plays and reverts audio-captures within the streamlit app.

The issue here is that I need to play the audio file when the user starts the recording, but I can't seem to get the logic of it right.

Right now I have this two functions:

```
def play_sweep(wavefile_name):
    audio_files_path = r'data/audio_files'
    read_file_path = os.path.join(audio_files_path, wavefile_name)
    # Extract data and sampling rate from file
    sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(read_file_path)
    sd.play(data, sample_rate)
    status = sd.wait()  # Wait until file is done playing

def audiorec():
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # Custom REACT-based component for recording client audio in browser
    build_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, "st_audiorec/frontend/build")
    # specify directory and initialize st_audiorec object functionality
    st_audiorec = components.declare_component("st_audiorec", path=build_dir)

    st.write('\n\n')

    # STREAMLIT AUDIO RECORDER Instance
    val = st_audiorec()
    # web component returns arraybuffer from WAV-blob
    st.write(
        'Audio data received in the Python backend will appear below this message ...')

    if isinstance(val, dict):  # retrieve audio data
        with st.spinner('retrieving audio-recording...'):
            ind, val = zip(*val['arr'].items())
            ind = np.array(ind, dtype=int)  # convert to np array
            val = np.array(val)             # convert to np array
            sorted_ints = val[ind]
            stream = BytesIO(
                b"".join([int(v).to_bytes(1, "big") for v in sorted_ints]))
            wav_bytes = stream.read()

        # wav_bytes contains audio data in format to be further processed
        # display audio data as received on the Python side
        st.audio(wav_bytes, format='audio/wav')
```

The `audiorec()` function, as stated in the docs of the library, refers to this:

```
import {
  Streamlit,
  StreamlitComponentBase,
  withStreamlitConnection,
} from "streamlit-component-lib"
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"

import AudioReactRecorder, { RecordState } from 'audio-react-recorder'
import 'audio-react-recorder/dist/index.css'

interface State {
  isFocused: boolean
  recordState: null
  audioDataURL: string
  reset: boolean
}

class StAudioRec extends StreamlitComponentBase<State> {
  public state = { isFocused: false, recordState: null, audioDataURL: '', reset: false}

  public render = (): ReactNode => {
    // Arguments that are passed to the plugin in Python are accessible

    // Streamlit sends us a theme object via props that we can use to ensure
    // that our component has visuals that match the active theme in a
    // streamlit app.
    const { theme } = this.props
    const style: React.CSSProperties = {}

    const { recordState } = this.state

    // compatibility with older vers of Streamlit that don't send theme object.
    if (theme) {
      // Use the theme object to style our button border. Alternatively, the
      // theme style is defined in CSS vars.
      const borderStyling = `1px solid ${
        this.state.isFocused ? theme.primaryColor : "gray"}`
      style.border = borderStyling
      style.outline = borderStyling
    }

    return (
      <span>
        <div>
          <button id='record' onClick={this.onClick_start}>
            Start Recording
          </button>
          <button id='stop' onClick={this.onClick_stop}>
            Stop
          </button>
          <button id='reset' onClick={this.onClick_reset}>
            Reset
          </button>

          <button id='continue' onClick={this.onClick_continue}>
            Download
          </button>

          <AudioReactRecorder
            state={recordState}
            onStop={this.onStop_audio}
            type='audio/wav'
            backgroundColor='rgb(255, 255, 255)'
            foregroundColor='rgb(255,76,75)'
            canvasWidth={450}
            canvasHeight={100}
          />

          <audio
            id='audio'
            controls
            src={this.state.audioDataURL}
          />

        </div>
      </span>
    )
  }


  private onClick_start = () => {
    this.setState({
      reset: false,
      audioDataURL: '',
      recordState: RecordState.START
    })
    Streamlit.setComponentValue('')
  }

  private onClick_stop = () => {
    this.setState({
      reset: false,
      recordState: RecordState.STOP
    })
  }

  private onClick_reset = () => {
    this.setState({
      reset: true,
      audioDataURL: '',
      recordState: RecordState.STOP
    })
    Streamlit.setComponentValue('')
  }

  private onClick_continue = () => {
    if (this.state.audioDataURL !== '')
    {
      // get datetime string for filename
      let datetime = new Date().toLocaleString();
      datetime = datetime.replace(' ', '');
      datetime = datetime.replace(/_/g, '');
      datetime = datetime.replace(',', '');
      var filename = 'streamlit_audio_' + datetime + '.wav';

      // auromatically trigger download
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.style.display = 'none';
      a.href = this.state.audioDataURL;
      a.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
    }
  }

  private onStop_audio = (data) => {
    if (this.state.reset === true)
    {
      this.setState({
        audioDataURL: ''
      })
      Streamlit.setComponentValue('')
    }else{
      this.setState({
        audioDataURL: data.url
      })

      fetch(data.url).then(function(ctx){
        return ctx.blob()
      }).then(function(blob){
        // converting blob to arrayBuffer, this process step needs to be be improved
        // this operation's time complexity scales exponentially with audio length
        return (new Response(blob)).arrayBuffer()
      }).then(function(buffer){
        Streamlit.setComponentValue({
          "arr": new Uint8Array(buffer)
        })
      })

    }


  }
}

// "withStreamlitConnection" is a wrapper function. It bootstraps the
// connection between your component and the Streamlit app, and handles
// passing arguments from Python -> Component.
// You don't need to edit withStreamlitConnection (but you're welcome to!).
export default withStreamlitConnection(StAudioRec)

// Tell Streamlit we're ready to start receiving data. We won't get our
// first RENDER_EVENT until we call this function.
Streamlit.setComponentReady()

// Finally, tell Streamlit to update our initial height. We omit the
// `height` parameter here to have it default to our scrollHeight.
Streamlit.setFrameHeight()
```

I know that if I want to run a python function with the click of a HTML button I need to use Flask, but I was wondering if with some conditions, given that I'm using streamlit and the streamlit_audio_recorder library, I could simply say (for example):

```
if HTMLbutton == Start Recording:
    play_sweep()
```

Comment: Are you avoiding using st.button intentionally? You should be able to just do a Streamlit button and call play_sweep() when it's clicked

Comment: No, I'm not avoiding it. `play_sweep()` starts when a button is pressed, only it is not visible here because I omitted it. The fact is that when I press that button, `play_sweep()` starts executing immediatly, while I need `play_sweep()` and `audiorec()` to be synchronized and play simultaneously, but I can't do it because when I execute `audiorec()` the HTML buttons appear and the user has to press another button to start the recording.